# Galois orbit of a $k_{s}$ - torus

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups

I have some trouble while reading a proof of a lemma in the book

*Conrad, Brian; Gabber, Ofer; Prasad, Gopal*, [**Pseudo-reductive groups.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316092439), New Mathematical Monographs 26. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-107-08723-1/hbk; 978-1-316-09243-9/ebook). xxiv, 665 p. (2015). [ZBL1314.20037](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1314.20037).

Here is the lemma:

> **Lemma C.4.4.** Let $G$ be a group scheme locally of finite type over a field $k$, $T$ is a maximal $k$-torus in $G$ and $K/k$ an extension field. If $G$ is smooth or commutative, or if $K/k$ is a separable extension, then $T_{K}$ is a maximal $K$-torus in $G_{K}$.

In the proof, the authors wrote:

> Suppose $G$ is connected and commutative. Any $k_{s}$-torus in $G_{k_{s}}$ has a $\text{Gal}(k_{s}/k)$-orbit consisting of finitely many $k_{s}$-tori, so by commutativity the collectively generate a $\text{Gal}(k_{s}/k)$-stable $k_{s}$-subtorus.

I don't know why a Galois orbit of a $k_{s}$-torus has only finite tori, can anybody explain this for me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess you can take an affine neighborhood $U$ of $1$ in your $k_s$-torus, affine means it is $Spec(A_s)$, locally finite type means $U$ can be chosen such that $A_s$ is a finitely generated $k_s$ algebra thus defined by finitely many algebraic equations whose coefficients are in a finite extension of $k$ so that $Gal(k_s/k)$ sends $A_s$ to finitely many different copies

Comment: @reuns I'm sorry if this question is silly but why those equations have coefficients in a finite extension of $k$? Is it related to the fact that every torus splits over a finite Galois extension or something else?

Comment: They have coefficients in $k_s\subset k^{alg}$ and finitely many algebraic numbers generate a finite extension. $Gal(k_s/k)$ corresponds to infinitely many isomorphisms $A_s\to \sigma(A_s)$ but there are only finitely many $\sigma(A_s)$

Comment: Thanks a lot. So now there can only be finitely many different $\sigma(U)$, right?